# Value of stat structure contained structure lost

Tags: c, unix, linked-list, stat

I'm trying to code the ls function from ground up. In order to do so, I created a linked list of structures containing the information of each file / structure.

Here is the structure :

```
typedef struct      s_ls
{
    char            *name;
    struct          stat stat;
    struct          s_ls *next;
}                       t_ls;
```

I then created a linked list :

```
t_ls    *ft_store(char *foldername)
{
    t_ls    *stock = NULL;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dent;
    dir = opendir(foldername);

    if(dir != NULL)
    {
        while((dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            stock = ft_add_elem(dent->d_name, stock);
            stat(stock->name, &(stock->stat));
        }
    }
    return (stock);
}
```

The ft_add_elem function mallocs a new structure, adds a new element in alphabtical order, and returns a pointer to the first element in the following manner :

```
t_ls    *ft_new_elem(char *name)
{
    t_ls    *tmp;
    if (!(tmp = malloc(sizeof(t_ls))))
        exit(1);
    tmp->name = ft_strdup(name);
    return (tmp);
}

t_ls    *ft_add_elem(char *name, t_ls *stock)
{
    t_ls *new;
    t_ls *check;

    new = ft_new_elem(name);
    if (!stock)
        return (new);
    check = stock;
    while (check && check->next && ft_strcmp(check->next->name, new->name) < 0)
        check = check->next;
    new->next = check->next;
    check->next = new;
    return (stock);
}
```

My problem is that when I go through the elements to print them out when the -l option is triggered for instance all stat structures are empty, except for the first one. This is however not the case if I print them from the same function that fills them up (ft_store).

Comment: That naming convention (t_ls) is horrible. Man it makes your code hard to read!

Comment: `stock->next` is unitialized

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that `ft_add_elem()` returns the pointer to the first item in the list, not the item just added.  You're keeping the list in sorted order (via the `ft_strcmp()` function).  So, you keep running `stat()` on the first name in the list — which will be `.` unless you've some unusual files in your (current) directory.

Fixing that is a bit more intricate.  It's probably best to do the `stat()` operation in `ft_add_elem()`.  Note, however, that you also have to worry about the path to the directory from which you're reading the entries.  If you're processing `.` (the current directory) only, then it'll work.  If you're processing other directories, you have to create the path to the file by prefixing the directory name to the file name.

It's also worth ensuring that the new element is fully initialized; it avoids accidentally undefined behaviour.

Here's some fixed code.  The functions with names starting `err_` are available from Github (https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) in `stderr.c` and `stderr.h`.  They're used to simplify error reporting.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ft_strcmp(s, t) strcmp(s, t)
#define ft_strdup(s)    strdup(s)

typedef struct      s_ls
{
    char            *name;
    struct          stat stat;
    struct          s_ls *next;
}                       t_ls;

static t_ls *ft_new_elem(char *name)
{
    t_ls    *tmp;
    if (!(tmp = malloc(sizeof(t_ls))))
        err_error("Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", sizeof(*tmp));
    tmp->name = ft_strdup(name);
    tmp->next = 0;
    tmp->stat = (struct stat){ 0 };
    return(tmp);
}

static t_ls *ft_add_elem(char *name, const char *dirname, t_ls *stock)
{
    t_ls *new;
    t_ls *check;

    new = ft_new_elem(name);
    if (!stock)
        return(new);
    check = stock;
    while (check && check->next && ft_strcmp(check->next->name, new->name) < 0)
        check = check->next;
    new->next = check->next;
    check->next = new;
    char pathname[strlen(dirname) + strlen(name) + 2];
    sprintf(pathname, "%s/%s", dirname, name);
    if (stat(pathname, &new->stat) < 0)
        err_sysrem("Failed to stat '%s': ", pathname);
    return(stock);
}

static t_ls *ft_store(char *foldername)
{
    t_ls    *stock = NULL;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dent;
    dir = opendir(foldername);

    if (dir != NULL)
    {
        while ((dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            stock = ft_add_elem(dent->d_name, foldername, stock);
        }
    }
    return(stock);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        argc = 2;
        argv = (char *[]){ ".", 0 };
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        t_ls *list = ft_store(argv[i]);
        t_ls *node = list;
        while (node != 0)
        {
            printf("Name: %s (size %llu)\n", node->name, node->stat.st_size);
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code uses a couple of compound literals, a feature of C99.  There are other ways to achieve the same effects.

Running the program (`rd37`) on a directory `etc` gave:

```
$ ./rd37 etc
Name: . (size 0)
Name: .. (size 2448)
Name: .gitignore (size 38)
Name: README.md (size 99)
Name: posix-opt-end.gif (size 65)
Name: posix-opt-start.gif (size 69)
Name: soq-head.mk (size 1618)
Name: soq-tail.mk (size 665)
Name: suppressions (size 16139)
Name: suppressions-macos-10.12.5 (size 4998)
$ ls -l etc
total 88
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff     99 Jul  9  2016 README.md
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jleffler  staff     65 Nov 10  2016 posix-opt-end.gif
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jleffler  staff     69 Nov 10  2016 posix-opt-start.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   1618 Jun 16 23:38 soq-head.mk
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    665 Aug 16  2016 soq-tail.mk
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  16139 Aug 20  2016 suppressions
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   4998 May 21 15:40 suppressions-macos-10.12.5
$
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much ! Now that I've seen it, it was quite obvious. Thank you for your time !!